# How do I click a button with the mouse on my page that then triggers a click on a link on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a learning management Wordpress theme that auto generates links to the previous and next video based on the video that you are on (Video 2 would have a prev link to video 1 and the next link to video 3 in the video description).

I want to add previous and next buttons on my custom video playback that when clicked trigger the previous and next links already generated by the WordPress theme.

How would I have a button that when clicked, clicks a link on the same page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML 5 VIDEO PLAYER</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Previous & Next Video Buttons -->
        <div id="video-arrows">
            <button type="button" id="previous-arrow"><a href="previous-video"></a><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="next-arrow"><a href="next-video"></a><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </div>
<div class="random-text">
        <h1>Video title</h1>
        <h4><span id="view-count"></span> views</h4>
        <p>Descriptions can convey valuable information that helps viewers find your videos in search results and understand what they’ll be watching. Well-written descriptions with the right keywords can boost views and watch time because they help your video show up in search results.</p>
        <a href="https://www.icloud.com/" target="_blank" id="previous-video">Previous</a>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" id="next-video">Next</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

window.onload = function() {
var nextArrow = document.getElementById('next-arrow')
var prevArrow = document.getElementById('previous-arrow')
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(nextArrow).on('click', function () {
      $('#next-video').click();
    });
    $(prevArrow).on('click', function () {
      $('#previous-video').click();
    });
});
}
```

It doesn't give any errors it just doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('#next-video')[0].click();`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="console.log('A')" id="A">A</button>
<button onclick="$('#A')[0].click()">B</button>
```